# STM32F767 Nucleo board printf to console

Tags: printf, stm32, nucleo, stm32cubeide

For the last couple of days I have been trying to get *printf* to work to print a debug message to a [STM32CubeIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#STM32) console. However, without any luck. I have gone through numerous forum threads and discussions and none of them appear to have fully solved this weird issue that is well known.

I have just generated a brand new project with [STM32CubeMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Cortex-M) and used a default configuration for the [Nucleo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#Nucleo_boards) board. I am just using a USB cable with a built-in [ST-LINK](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) to program the device.

So far, I have been suggested to add a few lines of code that apparently should have fixed the issue, but it didn’t:

```c
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif


PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);

  return ch;
}
```

I have also included:

```c
#include "stdio.h"
```

The actual code:

```c
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint8_t uart3_data[20] = "Hello from UART 3";
    uint8_t uart1_data[20] = "Hello from UART 1";
  /* USER CODE END 1 */


  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals. Initializes the flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */


  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */


  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM10_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */


  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */


    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      //Toggle_leds(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_0,100);

      HAL_Delay(1000);
      printf("UART Printf Example: retarget the C library printf function to the UART \n\r");
      printf("** Test finished successfully. ** \n\r");
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,uart3_data, sizeof(uart3_data), 50); // just to see what happens

      //HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,uart1_data, sizeof(uart1_data), 50); // just to see what happens
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */


}
```

When I open up a terminal and connect to the device, I can see the messages coming as expected:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k2JS.png)

However, I cannot understand why I am not able to see messages displayed on the [STM32CubeIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32#STM32) console. Am I missing some additional configuration?

Comment: STM32CubeIDE console displays the output of commands run locally on your PC. It's not meant to display serial output coming from the MCU. Either continue to use an external program or search and install an Eclipse add-in (like TM Terminal).

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get it working. Those who are having the same problem, just follow these simple steps:

1. Add a custom _write function to *syscalls.c* or even *main.c*:

   ```c
   int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
   {
     /* Implement your write code here. This is
        used by puts and printf for example */
     int i=0;
     for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
       ITM_SendChar((*ptr++));
     return len;
   }
   ```
2. In the debug configuration, enable the SWV tracing and set the core clock to the SYSCLK of your device (see the image below).

   [image: Debug configuration]
3. Debug your code and go to Windows → *Show view* → *SWV* → *SWV ITM Data console*

   Now you should have enabled SWV data console. Check the image below:

   [image: SWV ITM Data console]
4. Open up the SWV ITM Data console settings and make sure the port 0 is ticked (see the image below):

   [image: Enable port 0]
5. When you run the code, make sure start tracing is enabled:

   [image: Enable start tracing]
6. Have fun printing message to the console

A detailed guide on YouTube can be found in *[5. Tutorial. Use Serial Wire Viewer (SWV/SWO) via printf to debug STM32 in STM32CubeIDE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ti-1X8HfVrc&ab_channel=RADAS)*.

Unfortunately, there is still a hassle using this method. Every time you debug your code, you need to start tracing. There must be a simple method to display a message in the console without using the tracing.